# Unable to solve Cypress Eslint Parse error

Tags: typescript, cypress, eslint

I have installed lint ^0.8.19 and have the following setup in my cypress folder however each time I run my tests I see the following errors. Has anyone come across this and have managed to solve it?

This tsconfig.json file  is in mine Cypress Folder:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "types": ["cypress", "cypress-grep", "./support", "node"],
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "lib": ["DOM", "ES2015"],
      "strict": true,
      "allowJs": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "esModuleInterop": true
    },
    "include": ["**/*.ts"]
  }
```

The errors I am seeing from lint:

> Parsing error: ESLint was configured to run on `<tsconfigRootDir>/cypress/e2e/folder/test.cy.ts` using `parserOptions.project`: /users/lisasau/local_development/folder/tsconfig.jsonHowever, that TSConfig does not include this file. Either:- Change ESLint's list of included files to not include this file- Change that TSConfig to include this file- Create a new TSConfig that includes this file and include it in your parserOptions.

This is the error from cypress test run:

> ```
> Error: Webpack Compilation Error
> ./cypress/support/commands.ts
> Module not found:
> ```

Has anyone ran into this error and have managed to solve this?

I have tried to reinstall my npm packages and have tried to add targets to my eslint compiler.